# Xamarin iOS GetCell stretch cellView dynamically

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've got the following code that i've adapted from the Xamarin MobileCRM example:

```
[assembly: ExportCell(typeof(ListTextCell), typeof(ListTextCellRenderer))]

namespace Manager.iOS
{
class ListTextCellRenderer : TextCellRenderer
{
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableView tv)
    {
        var cellView = base.GetCell(item, tv);
        cellView.TextLabel.Lines = 0;                        
        return cellView;
    }               
}
}
```

Im wanting to have it that the TextLabel will stetch/wrap when it contains more text than the width of the device and therefore the rows will grow in size with it. When I set the Lines = 0; it wraps the label but the row height stays the same so every row just overlaps each other. How do I grow the row height as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to set HasUnevenRows or the RowHeight on your TableView

Answer (score 1):

In your tableView source you will want to override the following method

```
public override float GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var text = new NSString(yourTextHere);
    var size = text.StringSize(UIFont.FromName("FontName", fontSize), new SizeF(tableView.Frame.Width, 70)); // The 70 can be any number, the width is the important part
    return size.Height + 16; // 16 is for padding
 }
```